# Calculate SNR of Binary symmetric channel

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

I have generated a matrix of binary words and transmitted them over a binary symmetric channel with cross over probability P using Matlab's function bsc. At the receiver side, some of the code words will be received with errors.

Next I want to calculate the signal to noise ratio. In the research that I've done, the signal and noise are measured in terms of power using watts, however this cannot be done in my example. I ve also read that [Signal-to-noise ratio is sometimes used informally to refer to the ratio of useful information to false or irrelevant data in a conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio#Definition). Does this mean that the signal to noise ratio can be regarded as the number of bits received correctly vs the number of bits received incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't quite calculate a signal to noise ratio (SNR) since you don't know the noise power with a Binary Symmetric Channel (BSC). All you know with this channel model is that whatever the noise power is, it's causing errors with probability `P`.

At best you could compare it to the SNR of an equivalent system producing the same error probability. For example, you could consider a system where a BPSK signal is transmitted over an Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) channel and received by a hard decision decoder. In this case the relation between the SNR and the error probability is well know to be:

[image: P = \frac{1}{2} \mbox{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\mathcal E_ b}{N_0}}\right)]

or equivalently:

[image: \mbox{SNR} = \frac{\mathcal E_ b}{N_0} = \left(\mbox{erfc}^{-1}\left(2P\right)\right)^2]

But I should stress again that this only serves as a comparison and only makes sense when referencing the system you are comparing your BSC with (i.e. choosing a different system would yield a different P vs. SNR relationship).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what I have to do exactly, but your answer seems to be in line with the question I am trying to answer. I will mark your answer as a solution once I manage to implement it.

Comment: This is probably the best possible answer for the somewhat vague question

Comment: Thanks @SleuthEye. Basically what I did was generate P based on Eb/N0, and use that P for the BSC channel. What I was doing wrong initially was that I was trying to work the other way round, i.e get Eb/N0 based on P.

Answer (score 0):

Noise can be any source of radio interference that may or may not be causing your signal to be slower or at a higher chance of data corruption due to environmental radiation.

You could make up your own scale for measuring noise that is relevant.  For example, you can take a small sample of the ambient radio transmissions on the ~same frequency and use that as a factor in your ratio.

EDIT:
You may want to use a integrity algorithm such as the Hamming Algorithm to check and possibly repair data corruption.  There are many options available.

HEADER:
You can also craft a custom header format that only your application will use so you can easily filter out *noise that has nothing to do with your needs.